# How do I fix the error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, macos

when I try to run my app on the iOS simulator, it crashes and I get this error code: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

The code for the area that the error is showing up in is:

```
  var appData = [Section: [AppDetail]]()
for (sectionName, apps) in appDataPList {
  let appDetails: [AppDetail]
  appDetails = apps.flatMap(AppDetail.init(plistData:))
  let section = Section(rawValue: sectionName)!
  appData[section] = appDetails
}

return appData
```

Answer (score 0):

From the piece of code you've provided you're likely getting this error because you're force-unwrapping an optional with the "!" here: `let section = Section(rawValue: sectionName)!`.

Instead try this:

```
if let section = Section(rawValue: sectionName) {
   appData[section] = appDetails
} else {
   print("error creating section")
}
```

You can the work through the code and figure out why you're getting a nil value.

You should also read more about optionals [here](http://www.appcoda.com/beginners-guide-optionals-swift/).

Comment: I did that but it didn't fix the issue. It stopped it from crashing but it still doesn't show any of the apps. Got Discord or Skype so we I can explain a bit more.

Comment: You'll need to debug the reason that your getting the nil error. Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code?